# Accounts in corda

Tags: corda

Corda as a platform, how handles whether the person wants to do transfer an asset from one account to another is the owner of the account or not?
Or some other user who have access to node can also access to any account present on node.

Comment: On a side note, please edit the title of your post; turn it into a distinct question rather than a general title.

Answer (score 2):

- If you look at `AccountInfo` state which is the core of the accounts library; it has an attribute `host`, that's the node that hosts the account (the node where the account was created).
- The `host` is the `Party` that signs on behalf of the account, by signing with its key.
- So for instance if the `host` is the initiator of the flow, then they can sign on behalf of the account like this: (first you call `accountKey = RequestKeyForAccount()`; then `getServiceHub().signInitialTransaction(txBuilder, accountKey.getOwningKey());` .
- Now, in general when an initiator calls `CollectSignaturesFlow` so that the responding nodes sign; every node that responds will check the requested keys in the transaction and sign that transaction with all the keys that are requested **and it owns**.
- Following the point above, if the initiator wants to collect the signatures of 10 accounts that are hosted on another node; you don't need 10 `FlowSession`'s with the `host` node, you create only one `FlowSession` and pass it to `CollectSignaturesFlow`. The node (which is the `host` of the 10 accounts) will see in the responder flow that all 10 requested keys are owned by it, so it will sign with all 10 keys (meaning the `host` node signed on behalf of the 10 accounts).
- If those 10 accounts were hosted on different nodes (let's say 5 accounts on PartyA and 5 account on PartyB); then you have to create 2 `FlowSession`'s (one for PartyA which will sign on behalf of 5 accounts, and one for PartyB which will sign on behalf of the other 5).

Now back to your original question:

- If you are using the Tokens SDK:

  - If you are using the ready flows (e.g. `MoveFungibleTokens()`); then only the node that hosts the "from-account" can initiate the flow. This way the node that hosts the account signs the move transaction; which requires (by contract) the signature of the current holder (i.e "from-account"), and since the node that initiated the flow hosts that account, it can sign on behalf of it. The ready move flow (`MoveFungibleToken()`) doesn't have a `CollectSignaturesFlow()` call inside of it, meaning you cannot start that flow to move tokens that belong to an account that's not hosted on the initiating node, because that flow doesn't collect signatures of other nodes, so it cannot collect the signature of the "from-account" (i.e. the current holder of the tokens) because it's hosted on a different node.
  - So the only way to use a flow to move accounts of a "from-account" that's not hosted on the initiating node, is by creating a flow yourself which will use the utility functions of the Tokens SDK (e.g. `addMoveFungibleTokens()`) and then take care of collecting the signature of the "from-account" using `CollectSignaturesFlow` where the host signs the transaction in the responding flow.
- If you're not using the Tokens SDK, then like in the last point above; you have to create a transaction manually and make sure that you collect the signature of the "from-account" by calling the `CollectSignaturesFlow` where the `host` of the account signs on its behalf in the responder flow.