# Corda signing and identity storage

Tags: corda

How exactly the transaction is happening in Corda. Is it using node Identity for transaction signing. If I created multiple accounts under a node, will it use Node Identity for transaction signing or is it using account. Where the keys belongs to a node are stored in the Corda network? It will be great help if someone can provide the documentation link for more detail on transaction signing and node identity storage.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accounts in corda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63067829/accounts-in-corda)

Comment: @AlessandroBaffa Yes it partially answers to my query